# Cannot invoke splice(int, int) on the array type int[][]

Tags: processing

I have a short code which I can't seem to figure out. The biggest problem which I have is that I don't understand the error and cannot seem to find how I can change the type of my array.

```
int [][] spawnLocatiesCoins = new int [20][2];


void collectenVanCoins () {
  if (gameState == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
      if (key == 's' && dist(spawnLocatiesCoins[i][0], spawnLocatiesCoins[i][1], xPosPlayer1, yPosPlayer1) < 20) {
        println("catch" + i);
        score++;
        spawnLocatiesCoins.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I am **trying** to do is remove the `spawnLocationsCoins[i]` from my array. The error message which I get here is `Cannot invoke splice(int, int) on the array type int[][]`. I have tried several different approaches for the splice method. I have also tried using the `remove` method with no result.

Could someone explain to me how I can remove an item from a `int [][]` array.

Comment: Where are you getting the `splice()` function from? Java arrays to not have a `splice()` function. Are you trying to use Processing's `splice()` function? If so, you would call `splice()` directly and pass the array in as an argument. You can see an example in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/splice_.html). If that doesn't work, can you please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to use Processing [splice](https://processing.org/reference/splice_.html) function, however, that doesn't do what you want ("Inserts a value or an array of values into an existing array").

I'd say you are best off using an [ArrayList](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) instead of an array, where you can then just use the [.remove](https://processing.org/reference/IntList.html) function like this:

```
list.remove(index);
```

Because you want to store 2 values (x and y), you could make an ArrayList of int arrays

```
ArrayList<int[]> spawnLocatiesCoins = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

You can add values like this:

```
spawnLocatiesCoins.add(new int[]{x_value, y_value});
```

And access them like this:

```
spawnLocatiesCoins.get(index)[index_in_the_array];
```

You could also use [PVectors](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) (variables that can store 2/3 values (depending on whether you are making a 3D program)) instead of arrays, but you probably don't need them at this point.